# how to load others comments with out page refresshing

Tags: php, ajax

Loading comments others  automatically like facebook

**php code updated **

```
 <section class="panel-body">
```

```
<div class="container">

<div class="comment">
 <div class="commenter" name="comments">
 <img width="80px" height="80px" src="uploads/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>">

 </div>
  <div class="comment-text-area">
      <textarea class="textinput"id="comment"  name="comments" placeholder="Comment Here......"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" class="butn"name="compost">post comment</button> 


  </div>
</div>
</div>

    </div>          
</fotm> 


       <div id="comments">
<?php include'cajax.php'; ?>   
  </div> 



 </section>
</section>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#comments').load('cajax.php');
refresh();
});

    function refresh()
 {
  setTimeout( function() {
   $('#comments').load('cajax.php');
    refresh();
  }, 1000);
 }
  </script>
```

how to  load comments automatically without page refreshing I know its 
possible with ajax but how to implement code please help us

Comment: You need "Load more button" here is demo page and code http://www.codexworld.com/load-more-data-using-jquery-ajax-php-from-database/

Comment: see my queation please

Comment: then you have wrong title for topic, "how i can post a comment without page refreshing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first create another php file named comments.php or whatever you want and cut and paste the code that fetch the comment from DB in that file**
And in your main file where you want to show comments create a div , id="comments" or whatever you want .. and inside that div include the new php file like this

```
 <div id="comments">
<?php include'comments.php'; ?>   
</div>
```

now above that code paste the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#div_name').load('filename.php');
refresh();
});

function refresh()
{
    setTimeout( function() {
      $('#div_name').load('filename.php');
      refresh();
    }, 1000);
}
</script>
```

**Replace the div_name with the name of your div and filename.php .. with your file name**